# need help uploading images

Tags: angularjs, file, upload

I'm trying to upload an object file which contains 2 attributes, a name and a picture using AngularJS. I know that this topic has been treated multiple times but no matter what I read I can't seem to make it work. 
I'm using Java Spring for my server and when I try to upload a "Character" (name + picture) through my client I get this error in my server : "Required request body content is missing"...

Here is my code :

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $resourceProvider) {

$resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;

$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data) {
    if (data === undefined)
        return data;

    var fd = new FormData();
    angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
        if (value instanceof FileList) {
            if (value.length == 1) {
                fd.append(key, value[0]);
            } else {
                angular.forEach(value, function(file, index) {
                    fd.append(key + '_' + index, file);
                });
            }
        } else {
            fd.append(key, value);
        }
    });

    return fd;
}

$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = undefined;
```

And here is my service :

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource'])
.factory('Character', function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/myApp/character/:id',
        { id: '@id' },
        { update: { method: 'GET', transformRequest: angular.identity, headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }  } }
    );
})

.service('popupService', function($window){
    this.showPopup = function(message){
        return $window.confirm(message);
    }
});
```

And finally this is how I'm using it in my controller :

```
.controller('CharacterCreateController',function($scope,$state,$stateParams,Character){

$scope.character = new Character();

$scope.addCharacter = function(){
    $scope.character.$save(function(){
        $state.go('characters');
    });
}
```

})

Could anyone please help me ??? I really don't know what to do and it's my first time trying to upload files using Angular.

Comment: Hi, are you sure you need to write your own File uploader? There are many of them that you can simply reuse instead of facing issues someone already resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have an example somewhere that I can reuse?

Comment: Tell me one thing, are you gonna support IE9?

Comment: https://flowjs.github.io/ng-flow/ , https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload. I'm using https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload coz it support file uploading information like file size and progress in IE9 but needs Flash. Pick any you find simple looking.